# Remove UINavigationBar from view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I've embedded several VC's in a `UINavigationController`. I do not want to show the navigation bar.
I read that this method should remove it, but I cannot figure out who or what to call it on.

`[viewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

Can someone give me an example of how this is used?
Or any other method to remove the nav bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just don't want the navigation bar, do it like this:

```
UINavigationController *naviController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
naviController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

If you want to hide the navigation bar only in some vc, put bellow code in your `- (void)viewDidLoad` or some other place depends on your need:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

You call it on the root view controller. That is, the view controller you used to create the UINavigationController with the method:

– initWithRootViewController:

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, call it on the root view controller. No, the root view controller is not what you use to create the navigation controller. The root view controller is the view controller that you place into the navigation controller as "rootViewController".

Comment: Sorry I was assuming initWithRoowViewController was used to create the navigation controller. Answer is edited.